# Bitcoinqt 2009-2010

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, bitcoin-qt-setup

Im not asking if you can recover an account without phrase of wallet.dat file

I have several questions however

First what payment service did bitcoin qt first use, i remember i had to use debit and credit cards

My main is question is this, Does bitcoin core wallet have financial records from origination date of bitcoinqt

The leading point is i want to argue that despite policy they must have an actual record of who bought what bitcoin almost positive that i had to enter my name into the payment service and other info when buying

And you know its terrible knowing like 5-8 words of the passphrase 12-13 years later

Btw im not trolling im wondering if bitcoincore is willing to allow queries and tracking down financials would be a lot easier if i knew the third party service

Thanks not here to waste anyones time

Comment: Bitcoin Core never had a marketplace or exchange functionality, nor did it ever use a mnemonic seed. You might be thinking of blockchain.com instead.

Comment: Bitcoin-Qt didn't exist until the end of 2011, and the name Bitcoin Core has only been in use since 2014.

Answer (score 1):

What you seek does not exist.

Bitcoin is electronic cash. I find it often helps to think about paper cash when considering some aspect of Bitcoin.

The makers of leather wallets, say Gucci, do not maintain records of what paper banknotes you put into the leather wallet or where you spent them. You cannot ask Gucci where you got your money from or where it is now.

SImilarly Bitcoin Core developers do not and can not keep records of what you do with a Bitcoin core wallet. It is actually of paramount importance that they are unable to know what you do.

---

> what payment service did bitcoin qt first use, i remember i had to use debit and credit cards

None.

> Does bitcoin core wallet have financial records from origination date of bitcoinqt

No organisation, group or other person has any financial records relating to your use of "Bitcoin Core" software (such as bitcoin-qt).

Your wallet, if maintained continuously, has a record of your financial transactions stored locally on your device.

Each node in the global Bitcoin network has a copy of the blockchain (or access to a copy). Which includes every financial transaction carried out *directly* using the Bitcoin network. But they don't know which transactions relate to a specific named person.

> The leading point is i want to argue that despite policy they must have an actual record of who bought what bitcoin

Untrue. The people who develop an maintain Bitcoin core don't have any special records that are not public and already known or available to everyone worldwide.

> im wondering if bitcoincore is willing to allow queries.

The people who develop and maintain Bitcoin core don't have any relevant records. There is nothing to query. All their work is public so far as I know.

> and tracking down financials would be a lot easier if i knew the third party service

Knowing where you bought something is usually no help whatsoever in knowing where you put it or where and when you sold it.